# Price of an asian option with squared of average payoff

Tags: option-pricing, derivatives, asian-option

Is there a closed form solution of the following price formula? Assuming $dS_t=rSdt+\sigma S_t dW_t$ under the Q dynamics

$e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}_t^\mathcal{Q}[(\frac{(\int_0^T S_u du)}{T})^2]$

I know that the integral of a geometric brownian motion has no nice distribution, but is it the same with the square of the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $P$ dynamics of the underlying asset are:
\begin{align*}
dS=S(\mu dt+\sigma dB_t)
\end{align*}
That has the following solution under the $\mathcal{Q}$ dynamics:
\begin{align*}
S_t=S_0 e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+\sigma W_t}
\end{align*}
Where $W_t$ is the equivalent martingale with respect to the original geometric brownian motion. Define $Y_t=\int_0^t S_u du$, then according to Feynman-Kac the value of the replicating portfolio is given by
\begin{align*}
V_t&=e^{-r(T-t)}\frac{1}{T^2}\mathbb{E}_t^\mathcal{Q}[(Y_t+\int_t^T S_udu)^2)\\
&=\frac{e^{-r(T-t)}}{T^2} \mathbb{E}_t^\mathcal{Q}[Y_t^2 + 2Y_t \int_t^T S_u du + (\int_t^T S_u du)^2]\\
\end{align*}
So:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_t^\mathcal{Q}[\int_t^T S_u du]&=S_t \mathbb{E}_t^\mathcal{Q}[\int_t^T \frac{S_u}{S_t} du]\\
&=S_t \int_t^T e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(u-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathcal{Q}[e^{\sigma (W_u-W_t)}] du\\
\end{align*}
Since $W_u-W_t$ follows $\mathcal{N}(0, u-t)$ under $Q$. According to the m.g.f. 
\begin{align*}
&=S_t \int_t^T e^{r(u-t)}du\\
&=\frac{S_t}{r}(e^{r(T-t)}-1)\\
&=\frac{x}{r}(e^{r(T-t)}-1)
\end{align*}
Lets compute now the expectation of the square of the integral:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_t^\mathcal{Q}[(\int_t^T S_u du)^2]&=S_t^2 \mathbb{E}_t^\mathcal{Q}[\int_t^T \frac{S_u}{S_t}du \int_t^T \frac{S_v}{S_t}dv ]\\
&= S_t^2 \int_t^T \int_t^T \mathbb{E}^\mathcal{Q}[\frac{S_u}{S_t} \frac{S_v}{S_t}]dv du\\
\end{align*}
Lets focus on: $\mathbb{E}^\mathcal{Q}[\frac{S_u}{S_t} \frac{S_v}{S_t}]$, lets assum $t \leq v \leq u$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}^\mathcal{Q}[\frac{S_u}{S_t} \frac{S_v}{S_t}&=\mathbb{E}^\mathcal{Q}[e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(u-t)+\sigma(W_u-W_t))}e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(v-t)+\sigma(W_v-W_t))}]\\
&=e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(u-t)+(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(v-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathcal{Q}[e^{\sigma(W_u-W_v)+2\sigma (W_v-W_t)}]\\
&=e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(u-t)+(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(v-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathcal{Q}[e^{\sigma(W_u-W_v)}]\mathbb{E}^\mathcal{Q}[e^{2\sigma(W_u-W_t)}]\\
&=e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(u-t)+(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(v-t)}e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(u-v)}e^{2\sigma^2(v-t)}\\
&= e^{ur}e^{u(r+\sigma^2)}e^{-t(2r+\sigma^2)}
\end{align*}
So:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_t^\mathcal{Q}[(\int_t^T S_u du)^2]&=2S_t^2 \int_t^T \int_t^u e^{ur}e^{u(r+\sigma^2)}e^{-t(2r+\sigma^2)}dv du\\
&= \frac{2x^2}{r+\sigma^2}(\frac{1}{2r+\sigma^2}e^{(2r+\sigma^2)(T-t)}-\frac{1}{r}e^{r(T-t)}+\frac{r+\sigma^2}{(2r+\sigma^2)r})
\end{align*}
Mixing everything together we get:
\begin{align*}
V(t,x,y)&=\frac{y^2}{T^2}e^{rt-rT}+\frac{1}{T^2}\frac{2xy}{r}(1-e^{rt-rT})\\
&+ \frac{1}{T^2}\frac{2x^2}{r+\sigma^2}(\frac{1}{2r+\sigma^2}e^{(r+\sigma^2)(T-t)}-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{r+\sigma^2}{(2r+\sigma^2)r}e^{-r(T-t)})
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you sure that your derivation is correct? It doesn't look so to me.

Comment: I can check it, but it seems ok to me. It satisfies the SDE $V_t  + rxV_x+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x^2 V_{xx} +x V_y=rV$ and boundary conditions. Why it does not look correct to you?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is known in closed form.  See https://www.rocq.inria.fr/mathfi/Premia/free-version/doc/premia-doc/pdf_html/asian_doc/asian_doc.html section 5.1 which references an older Geman-Yor paper.

Comment: This gives a closed form for the Laplace transform of the Asian call option. Computing the second moment is a much simpler task.

Comment: Agree the moment calc is simpler than laplace transform.  The reference I linked gives both; equation for moments is (11) in section 5.1.

Comment: My bad. Good link.

Answer (score 2):

A few tips. First note that $e^{-rt}S_t$ is a martingale. So make it appear and then integrate by part to rewrite $\int S_u du$ as a stochastic integral. Finally use the Ito isometry property.